# has_many and belongs_to assosiations in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

everyone
I have a question related relationships in Rails. I have a Student model

```html
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    ....
    has_many :histories, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And my History model

```html
class History < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :student
 
end
```

I try to this code to get all histories that belong to a student

```html
def history
@histories = @student.histories.paginate(:per_page =>25, :page => params[:page])
end
```

Method history belongs to Students controller, and is called via history_path(student).
But i got an error :no such column: histories.student_id. I thought that when i make relationships in Rails via belongs_to and has_many necessary id's are created automatically?

Comment: in software nothing is going to automatically until and unless it is define somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No they are not automatically created. Just create a migration like this:

```
rails g migration add_student_id_to_histories student_id:integer
```

and then run:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

This needs to be done for all the relations. Rails doesn't automatically creates this. You need to do this manually.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. But i have a question if i have to create all necessary id's manually for setting relationships, what is the point to use has_many, belongs_to relationships? Sorry for stupid question. In some tutorials i saw them creating this relationships, but didn't saw when they created those id's, therefore i started thinking that id's generated automatically. (for example railsforzombies.org 2 lecture).

Comment: These associations are useful at many places. You can find the advantages of `ORM` on google. As the `Active Record` in rails is implementation of `ORM`. I am not a pro at this but what I noticed that ORM simplifies the SQL queries as you don't need to write that. It increases the development speed. More understandability of code.

Answer (score 0):

You've to try running:

```
rails g migration create_histories student:references; rake db:migrate
```

This will create histories table with student_id.
Or add user:references to your existing histories table

Deep answered first while I was typing, avoid my answer.